# What is difference between snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca() and snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc()?

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

I have seen some codes for capture/playback using alsa api. Some of them are using `snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc()` while some are using `snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca()`.

What is the difference between them other than one is function and one is macro.
Is snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca() macro replaced by snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca()` uses `alloca()` to allocate the structure on the stack. This means that it is automatically freed when your function returns.

`snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc()` uses `malloc()`. You are responsible to call `snd_pcm_hw_params_free()` when it is no longer needed.